# How to detect the installation package is not modified？

Tags: ios

How to detect the installation package is not modified.
For example, someone changed my app,how could i know the app had something different ,and shut down the pirate app, or alert for user:The package is damaged, please download it again.

Comment: question is not clear.. could you elaborate?

Comment: Do you mean the link redirected?

Comment: Check the signature...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're distributing your app via AppStore, then there will be no chance of your app gets pirated or feeling seek. AppStore is providing highly secure ways to distribute your app. So there's no chance that your app was pirated. However, you can add some checksum which can be possible to check on star-up. If its changed then the binary was changed.

Comment: Apps from the Mac App store can most definitely be cracked.

Comment: How to detect the integrity of your application?Check the binary?